# json_encode and accent

Tags: php, javascript, json, encoding

I have an array that is json encoded and stored into a database. All my php files are utf8, and my mysql database is utf8_general_ci.

My array contains names  which may contain accentuated character, which json_encode transform into \u characters. This array get stored into my database. When I use jQuery.parseJSON, the accentuated character show properly.

```
info = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
console.log(info);

//"Bob Épine" which is good
```

BUT when I want to use json_decode in PHP the \u characters stays.

```
print_r($this->opts['name']);
echo $this->opts['name'];

//Bob \u00c9pine
//Bob u00c9pine
```

I found out this function [PHP: Replace \u characters in json string](http://www.avoid.org/?p=67), is this the way to go?
It does work, but it seem to avoid the problem instead of fixing it.

Comment: Already tried `utf8_decode` for each `$this->opts['name']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, storing JSON in a DB table sounds like a flawed application design, but setting that aside for a second...

This sounds like [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) territory to me. By which I mean, it sounds like you are not escaping the `\` when you insert the data into the database. This means it is getting stripped out of the string, so all you end up with is `uxxxx` instead of `\uxxxx`, which means that they cannot be decoded.

Now, ways around this are many and varied, but the first thing you need to do is to ensure that the data is inserted into the database correctly, and the encoded JSON string is identical when it comes out to the one you put it. If you do this and you find that you are still having a problem with this, I have a function I wrote a while ago which will convert unicode code points to their binary representations (*which I am just finding for you*)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you pointed toward the error. The data in the database was indeed different, as you said the \ was removed. I fixed it with addslashes it work well now. But I'm still wondering when this \ get removed.  print_r(json_encode($options)); written just before the mysql insert show the good value, but the inserted value doesn't have the \.

Comment: @LucCR That's because backslash is also the (assuming MySQL?) database escape character, so MySQL interprets it as an escape sequence and eats it. Note that addslashes is not really safe for escaping database data - what database are you using and, if MySQL, which extension are you using to communicate with it?

Comment: It is a mysql database, and since this is an old project it uses the mysql extension. Same goes for the database structure, which i have no control over.

Comment: @LucCR Well you should definitely be using `mysql_real_escape_string()` over `addslashes()`. Despite the bad rep it gets it's actually completely safe as long as you never execute a `SET NAMES` query, which is something that nobody ever really does anyway.

Comment: Finally the solution of all my problems. I figured I didn't need to mysql_real_escape_string my json_encode data before inserting it but seems like it was a bad idea.

Comment: @DaveRandom storing JSON in a DB table is a flawed applcation design? I don't see why. I do that with two of my websites to avoid huge tables when I really don't need to be able to parse the data correctly.

Comment: @David天宇Wong I admit that's something of a sweeping statement but it's generally true. Most of the time JSON is used as data *transport* - a container for some data with some semantic meaning. In this case, you should store the data with it's meaning - break it up into its relevant, relative parts and store them in their appropriate places. It's quite rare that the JSON itself is the data.

Comment: @David天宇Wong For a concrete example consider two parts of the same application (even the same request) - an ajax request that sends some data to the server. The application itself should break this data up into the relevant parts and store them separately, because the application data is *within* the JSON. Now imagine I want to start logging raw request bodies for debugging - in this case the JSON itself is the data and I would store it in its raw, encoded format.

Answer (score 1):

PHP json_decode does not play well with some, if not all, UTF-8  non ASCII characters (>1 byte). In prototype.js I had to add a new JSON encoding function which would encode all non-ASCII characters (I don't have that code anymore).

Try [json_encode](http://phpjs.org/functions/json_encode) from the [phpjs](http://phpjs.org/packages/configure) library.

Comment: that was the case! used phpjs from nodejs